# Can't connect to machine via RDP running Cisco AnyConnect VPN (linux) on destination machine

Tags: linux, mac, lan, cisco-anyconnect

Hello I have a personal machine a Mac where is my principal work station and from here I connect to a Linux machine, the Linux machine needs to connect to Cisco AnyConnect, I installed linux64-4.10.03104 all components [dart, iseposture, nvm, posture, vpn], but when I connect the Linux Machine disapears from the LAN, I have active the option to have 'Discoverable over Lan(if configured)', no idea what the configuration should be, I don't know what to do for this case to have this flow working correctly, it's mandatory the use of AnyConnect due to the authentication factor, the Linux machine is running debian 11

so, I want to be able to connect via RPD to my Linux machine from my Mac machine with the Cisco AnyConnect active in the Linux machine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.